# Problem with repeating numbers in a file for key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have to return quantity of solved task by each person.
key - id number, value - number of task

```
1, 2
1, 2
1, 3
2, 2,
2, 7
```

correct output:

```
{1:2, 2:2}
```

and i only have {1:2, 2:1} because the following code ignores 2, 2. how to solve it?
code:

```
d = {}
with open(filename) as file:
    for i in file:
        for line in file:
            i = list(map(int, line.split(',')))
            if i[1] not in d:
                if i[0] not in d:
                    d[i[0]] = 1
                else:
                    d[i[0]] += 1
print(d)
```

Comment: I think the correct output should be `{1:3, 2:2}`

Comment: I think the idea is to count distinct tasks that people worked on; `(1, 2)` appears twice so person 1 only worked on 2 distinct tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the line containing `2,2` ends with a comma. This causes `line.split()` to return a wrong result as it tries to convert an empty string into an `int`. After removing it, the list has the correct length and the expected result is returned.

Comment: This has no effect whatsoever on the algorithm, since the code only uses indices 0 and 1 anyway.

Comment: It throws `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'` because it tries to convert an empty string into `int`. After removing the comma, it returns the (authors) expected result.

Comment: Given that the question reports an incorrect output rather than such an error, the chances are that that's just an accident made when copying the input data into the question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this task - first we need to ignore duplicate pairs like `(1, 2)` which appears twice, and then we need to count how many tuples each person appears in. We can solve the first part using a set, and the second part using a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```py
from collections import Counter

with open(filename) as file:
    pairs = { tuple(map(int, line.split(',')[:2])) for line in file }

d = Counter(person for person, _ in pairs)
```

The reason your original code gave the wrong results is that it only tests if the task has already been counted; it ignores `(2, 2)` because the task 2 has already been counted for person 1. We should only ignore true duplicates where both the person and task are repeated, not just when the task is repeated.

A few other details: your original code had two nested loops over the lines in the file, which are unnecessary; the `[:2]` gets rid of any empty strings if there is an extra comma in some line; and the pairs must be tuples, not lists, so that they can be stored in a set.